# firebase_app__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, webpack, babel-loader

### My error as per the title is firebase_app__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ is not defined

Im using *import* to declare firebase in LoadModel.js

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/analytics";
import "firebase/firestore";
```

after being bundled by webpack which uses babel-loader the module appears as not defined

`npm i firebase` has been executed along with every other node module I needed

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const CircularDependencyPlugin = require('circular-dependency-plugin');

module.exports = {
  optimization: {
    sideEffects: true,
  },
  entry: './src/scripts/app.js',
  output: {
      path: __dirname + "/dist",
      filename: 'app.bundle.js',
      sourceMapFilename: "[name].js.map"
  },
  mode: 'none',
  devtool: "source-map",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new CircularDependencyPlugin({
      // exclude detection of files based on a RegExp
      exclude: /a\.js|node_modules/,
      // include specific files based on a RegExp
      include: /src/,
      // add errors to webpack instead of warnings
      failOnError: true,
      // allow import cycles that include an asyncronous import,
      // e.g. via import(/* webpackMode: "weak" */ './file.js')
      allowAsyncCycles: false,
      // set the current working directory for displaying module paths
      cwd: process.cwd(),
    })
  ]
};
```